# Apache Solr - OR in filter query

Tags: apache, solr

Is it possible to search (with apache Solr) for items which are in one of few categories using filter query, e.g. items in category 'computers' OR 'phones'

When I want to search for items in category computers AND phones I type:

```
select/?q=...&fq=cat:computers&fq=cat:phones
```

but it is possible to use `OR` instead of `AND`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use

```
fq=cat:(computers OR phones)
```

Comment: Hello i have got params={start=1&q=file_content+:+cześć*&wt=javabin&fq=file_create_user:\-1+AND+file_parents_folder:\(341\+AND\+4222\)&version=2&rows=25} status=400 QTime=2 and i have got error Invalid Number: (341 AND 4222)

Comment: would this make it a single key in the filter cache or two different keys in the filter cache (one for computer and one for phone)?

Comment: Single key in filter cache

Answer (score 53):

A filter query is just a query -- as complex as you'd like. So, you can certainly build up a query, e.g.,

```
fq=(cat1:val1 OR cat2:val2 OR (cat3:(val3 AND val4)))
```

...or whatever.

The only difference between a filter query and a plain-old query (besides memory and caching issues, which you might want to also think about) is that a filter query doesn't affect the relevancy scores at all. But in terms of complexity, you can do whatever you want.